# firebug 1.5 is not working in Firefox 3.5.7

Tags: firefox, firebug, version

Firebug 1.5 is not working in Firefox 3.5.7

how to fix it, 
or I must to restore to previous version?

Comment: This is not the place for questions of this sort

Comment: A programmer can't ask a question about a developer tool on a programming Q&A site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 is out. Try to update your browser first.

Newest version of Firebug - 1.5 works with Firefox 3.6 without problems. Not sure why it's not working on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should raise this on the [Firebug discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug).

Answer (score 0):

try disabling firequery, firerainbow, whatever firebug addon you might have...